# List view footer should be attached to bottom but at the end of list view it should be fixed at some height

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display a footer at the end of list view but when list becomes scrollable footer should be displayed at bottom and visible.Currently when I add footer view it is at the end of list view always and when list view has more items footer is not visible.,for showing footer I need to scroll down till the end of list view.

Comment: post your xml file and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do add a footer layout to listview and also add it to the end of the listview and  implement the AbsListView.OnScrollListener in your activity and in onScroll() method method you can disable the footer layout in this way you can achieve what you desire

Comment: Let me try this.Thanks for yr reply. It seems that it'll work.

Comment: i have implemented this in my application

Comment: Hi @Pramod Yadav  onscrll is called in every time I install the app.can u post some code?

Comment: if you don't want to start it every time and only show it first time save a boolean value in your sharedprefrences and when the listview become scrollable assign it false and according to this value set values of your footer and other view